# ¿Como leer entrada de datos desde teclado con NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy tratando de leer la entrada de datos desde teclado en NodeJS, quisiera saber como hacer esto de la manera en que java tiene su scanner o c++ tiene su cin algo parecido, espero darme a entender.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Nodejs** provee nativamente la función `openStdin()` para aceptar entradas por teclado, aquí un ejemplo:

```
console.log("Escribe tu nombre:");
const stdin = process.openStdin();

stdin.addListener("data", (data) => {
    console.log("Tu nombre es: " + data.toString());
    //process.exit();
})
```